# I need to filter hyphen(-) and space(" ") in my string, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

This is the code I am using (but it only works for hyphens not for spaces)

```js
console.log(
    "some - text".replace(/\s\-/g, '').toLowerCase()
)
```

Can anyone point out what is wrong in this RegEx ?

Comment: Seems to work as expected - regex removes the space and the hyphen and leaves the space after the hyphen alone

Comment: I need the spaces also to go away @mplungjan

Comment: `/[\s\-]/g` should be sufficient (if not the most efficient; didn't try anything else).

Comment: Your regex only removes the first occurrence of hyphen or space. Try this `/\s*\-*/g`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The regex you have removes the space and the dash, leaving the second space

You need other regex to remove all spaces

```js
console.log(
    "some - text".replace(/\s\-/g, '') // space and dash
)

console.log(
    "some - text".replace(/\s-\s/g, '') // space before and after a dash
)


console.log(
    "some     -        text".replace(/\s+\-\s+/g, '') // any whitespace before and after
)


console.log(
    "so- me     -        te-xt".replace(/\s|-/g, '') // all spaces and all dashes, can be written as a acharacter class [\s-]
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use`\W` for non-word character:

```
console.log("some - text".replace(/\W/g, '').toLowerCase())
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is matching "(1 occurrence of some space)(definitely followed by 1 occurrence of ad ash)".  You want it to match any occurrence of those, so use a character class in your regex (see: [MDN WebDocs: JavaScript Character Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Character_Classes), with brackets, `/[\s\-]/g`, like so:

```js
console.log(
    "some - text".replace(/[\s-]/g, '').toLowerCase()
)
```

Want to replace another character?  Just throw it into the class and you're good to go.

Comment: Ah, another good point, updated to remove the unnecessary escaping on `\-`.  I wanted to introduce the OP to character classes, because adding/removing from the list of characters doesn't require an extra `|`.